# How to solve expressions in MVEL containing Float Values?

Tags: java, mvel

My expression is like this : `($a+$b)/$c`

```
String expr = "($a+$b)/$c";
Float sum = Float.valueOf("2.2");
HashMap<String, Float> valueMap =  new HashMap<String,Float>();
valueMap.put("$".concat(a)), sum);
sum = sum + Float.valueOf("1");
valueMap.put("$".concat(b)), sum );
sum = sum + Float.valueOf("1");
valueMap.put("$".concat(c)), sum );
VariableResolverFactory myVarFactory = new MapVariableResolverFactory();

Serializable compileExpression = MVEL.compileExpression(mtrExprD, valueMap); // here,     Only a map of < String,Object > is allowed.

MVEL.executeExpression(compileExpression, myVarFactory); // This should return me a float Value.
```

`MVEL.executeExpression()` returns an Object ; I want `myExpression` to return a float value instead of an Object. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mvel always return the object, we need to check the `instanceOf` for say `Boolean`, `Float` etc.
Also while doing calculation using arithmetic operators , be on a safer side to use null safe values.

for eg, if

your exp is `a * b`, and if a or b is `null`, then Mvel gives result as **false**.

Answer (score -1):

```
MVEL#executeExpression  return the Object
```

You have to cast it in Float

```
Float result = (Float) MVEL.executeExpression(compileExpression, myVarFactory);
```

like this

```
Serializable  compiled = MVEL.compileExpression("x * y"); 
Map<String, Integer> vars = new HashMap<>();
    vars.put("x", new Integer(5));
    vars.put("y", new Integer(10));
    // Executes the compiled expression
Integer result = (Integer) MVEL.executeExpression(compiled, vars);
```

See Mvel [doc](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Getting+Started+for+2.0)

Comment: Thank you user35736644892. I tried something like this. I hope, this may not be the right solution for this. please suggest, if anyone has better solution.

Could anyone please suggest me how to use ParserContext (Please focus some light on this, Am unaware about this) to solve this problem ?

Comment: I was trying converting into float - but i got class cast exception- cannot convert to Double to Float